# How do I add multiple foreign keys which refer to the same table in EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two tables which contain transaction between user.  I try adding 2 foreign keys one for the request user and another one for the receive user, but it gives me this error

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Transaction.UserRequest' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Here is my code.

```
public class user
{
   [Key]
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
public class Transaction
{
   [Key]
   public int TransactionId { get; set; }
   public string TransactionData { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("RequestId")]
   public User UserRequest { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ReceiveId")]
   public User UserReceive { get; set; }
}
```